Can i implement a read-write lock by using cas functions in Windows driver
My implement for the lock is in
code
Is the implement i code block a running ok?
If the implement is wrong, how to fix it?
If the read-write lock can not implement by cas function, How to implement a read-write lock running in any IRQL? Or where provide a implement of read-write lock can running in any IRQL that i can use?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/reader-writer-spin-locks
